Cómo se llaman los agujeros hechos accidentalmente en las camisas?
Hace un par de años, me hice un agujero en la camisa sin querer cuando se me enganchó en el picaporte de una puerta. Después, en una charla random con un señor en un evento le mostré la camisa y mientras le estaba contando lo que me pasó me responde: ‘Eso se llama ...’ y metió un término bien específico que no me lo puedo acordar. Alguna sugerencia alguien? Juro que era una palabra muy rara, no vale nada como ‘hueco’, ‘hoyo’, ‘orificio’, etc.

Por supuesto, no será lo que buscas, pero, como curiosidad, mi madre lo llamaba un "siete", por la forma de rasgarse el tejido, un tramo en el sentido de la trama y otro en el de la urdimbre.

No me suena que sea eso, pero todo sirve, gracias!

Ahora que lo pienso podría ser perfectamente eso. Quizá me hice la idea de que era una palabra rara y en realidad nada que ver. Veremos qué otras ofertas hay.

No me viene a la mente nada específico de telas, menos de camisas, pero de uso general  (nada raras aquí por mi tierra) rotura, boquete, desgarro/e.

Se llaman agujeros: https://www.cueroliquido.es/content/65-rotos-yo-agujeros-en-ropa-de-cuero-y-piel

No se cuál haya sido exactamente la palabra que oyeras de ese señor. Buscando en el diccionario hay algunas candidatas que a mi también me habrían sonado  tan extrañas como desconocidas,  que son sinónimos de agujero, como:

huraco

Y por rotura accidental podrías haber oido

cisura


f. Rotura o abertura sutil que se hace en cualquier cosa.

Más especificamente, encuentro que —para "rotura accidental"— existe también en castellano el término

piquete
1 (...)
2. m. Agujero pequeño que se hace en las ropas u otras cosas.
3...

Es interesante ver que el término piquete  aparece también dentro de un libro que encontré —en búsquedas de Google Books— en el que se analiza el campo semántico de agujero en español, donde seguramente podrías hallar el término que alguien usó y se esconde en  algún pliego de tus recuerdos
(Aunque dudo, porque quizás a este último piquete lo hubieras retenido, porque tenemos el término, en Arg., para denominar los "cortes" de calles o rutas producto de movilizaciones de personas protestando con reclamos de distintos tipos)
